# Is it possible to allocate resources for a partial openmp partial mpi program?

Tags: python, fortran, mpi, openmp, slurm

I'm working with a python program which, using MPI, makes calls to many (serial) fortran programs and collects their outputs. Prior to these fortran calls, I need to add a different fortran call to a program with an extremely expensive nested loop routine. I'm able to get this expesnive routine running in a reasonable time with openmp using an entire node of cpus (30-40) for threads, but I don't necessarily need this shared memory allocation for the subsequent fortran calls. For example, with 1 node having 40 cores, is it possible to allocate 1 task per node + 40 cpus per task for the openmp part, then switch to 40 tasks per node + 1 cpu per task for the following MPI part?

EDIT:
Here are some more details of the code. The MPI is handled by the python wrapper, executing calls to subprocess in parallel to run the serial fortran programs. The new program that uses openMP is also fortran. I use openMP to take advantage of the dynamic scheduling to speed up the for-loops, and also because calling an MPI-compiled fortran program from mpi4py I hear is bad news.

Here is a code sample that outlines the workflow I would like to have for more than 1 node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
from copy import deepcopy
import subprocess
from shutil import copy2
import os

def run_test(input_list):

    # Init MPI
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    comm_size = comm.Get_size()

    # Run the expensive program1 using openMP (40 cpus, 1 task, 40 threads per task)
    # This generates an output file used as input by program2
    if rank == 0:
        expensive_task = customFortranClass('program1')
        statement = os.path.join(task.absPathToExe, task.exeName)
        proc = subprocess.Popen([statement], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
        out,err = proc.communicate()
                                                                                                                                  
    # Prepare tasks for program2, to be run using MPI (80 cpus, 80 tasks, 1 thread per task)
    task_list = []
    task_template = customFortranClass('program2') 
    if rank==0:
        for inp in input_list:
            task = deepcopy(task_template)
            task.updateInputs(inp)
            task_list.append(task)
    task_list = comm.bcast(task_list, root=0)

    # Run Tasks Round Robin
    i = rank
    finished = []
    while True:
        if i > len(task_list)-1: break
        i += comm_size
        
        task = task_list[i]
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.makedirs(task.uniqueRunDirectory)

        # Copy inputs for program2 into unique run directory
        # Input files are 1) output from expensive task 
        #                 2) namelist file with unique input from input list
        copy2(expensive_task.outputFilename, task.uniqueRunDirectory)
        task.writeNML()

        statement = os.path.join(task.absPathToExe, task.exeName)

        # Run it
        os.chdir(task.uniqueRunDirectory)
        proc = subprocess.Popen([statement], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
        out,err = proc.communicate()
        task.output = out
        os.chdir(cwd)
        
        finished.append(task)

    # Gather list of lists on rank 0
    results_list = None
    results_list = comm.gather(finished, root=0)
    # Flatten
    if rank == 0:
        results = [item for sublist in results_list for item in sublist]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list = range(80)
    run_test(input_list)
```

The script is executed for example using slurm job scheduler, with a bash script like below. Though, per my question, I am unsure exactly what the contents of this file should be.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p my_clusters_queue
#SBATCH -J my_jobname
#SBATCH -o job_%A.out
#SBATCH -t 0-08:00
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1 # Or 40?
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40 # Or 1?

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=40
export OMP_STACKSIZE=64m
ulimit -s unlimited

mpirun ./my_script.py
```

Comment: A lot of stuff can be done. You can easily put your other processes to rest using MPI_BARRIER  and use threads in the root process. Likely much easier  than spawning and respawning. The question is, whether it makes sense. Wouldn't it be better to distribute the data between all processes and do everything in MPI?

Comment: The MPI is handled by the python wrapper, executing calls to subprocess in parallel to run the serial fortran programs. The new program that uses openMP is also fortran. I use openMP to take advantage of the dynamic scheduling to speed up the for-loops, and also because calling an MPI-compiled fortran program from mpi4py I hear is bad news. I'm more confused about the scheduler. If I request 1 task per node won't the scheduler fix this for the duration of my programs runtime and I'll only be able to run 1 MPI task?

Comment: It looks like you have to show us much more details about your setup. Do not use comments for important information, [edit] your question instead. We need to see your script that runs the programs and requests the resources.